# Why is Django authentication is now working for AbstractUser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

So I have these Django models in the `users` app, and I have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` to settings.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Supplier(User):
    company_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain=models.CharField(max_length=30)
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'supplier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'suppliers'
        
class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    is_hub_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'worker'
        verbose_name_plural = 'workers'
```

I also created an authenetication endpoint using Django rest framework. Surprisingly when I authenticate the admin everything works well. When I create a supplier and try to authenticate them. They always return invalid credentials. Here are my API views

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth
import jwt

class LoginView(GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        username = data.get('username', '')
        password = data.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            auth_token = jwt.encode({'username': user.username}, settings.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
            serializer = UserSerializer(user)
            data = {'user': serializer.data, 'token': auth_token}
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            # SEND RES
        return Response({'detail': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing, you should check `AUTH_USER_MODEL` keyword in setting file.
E.g. `AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<module>. User'`.

Regarding your case, the root cause is not yet [custom your authenticate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) method in your backend. You defined Supplier and Worker which are inherited from the User class.

Also, you can refer to [this link](https://www.beyondscale.tech/multiple-custom-user-auth-models-in-django-rest-framework) for detail.